# How can I accept Bitcoin as a payment without a 3rd party gateway

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, php, website-integration

I want to create a website where users can pay with Bitcoin. However I want to create my own payment gateway because I do not want to rely on services like BitPay. I want a unique BTC address for every user where the users can send money to this wallet and then spend the coins on the site.
I heard that it is possible with bitcoin-cli/bitcoind. I also have high skills in PHP and Linux so this isn’t a problem.

Comment: You can write your own php software that does RPC calls to your bitcoin node, see https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.18.0/ for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by getting into the Bitcoin Core RPC interface.

I also did a talk about it in German [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS03lQQRYFc). My solution is completely independent of any 3rd party software.

Comment: Video looks interesting. Do you have this php code on github?

Comment: @Prayank Not all parts of it, only the wrapper. See the comments section in the video but as I said I only started with a PHP website that has a startpage, a login page and a secured page that only logged in users can view. Keep in mind that the wrapper I used in the video is not 100% complete, nor up-to date. Please use something that is actively maintained. For example Bitcoin.php

Answer (score 4):

There are several solutions out there and currently the most hyped one is probably [BTC-Pay](https://btcpayserver.org/). It also supports lightning, so you should be pretty future-ready.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Bitcoin, I would advise you to play around btc wallet on testnet you could check mycelium for instance and get some btc via [faucet](https://coinfaucet.eu/en/btc-testnet/). You need to understand that you don't need any third party for interacting with bitcoins, you just require a wallet. A wallet is a program that handle [UTXOs](https://learnmeabitcoin.com/glossary/utxo), craft transactions and broadcast them to **bitcoind** nodes (or other compliant full node implementation), waiting for them to be mine. As you're developper, I highly recommend you to buy *[Mastering Bitcoin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491954388) from Andreas M. Antonopoulos*.

After than, you will simply design you're backend so that you can accept bitcoin payment, there is many open source project for your needs as [btcpayserver](https://btcpayserver.org/) or [bitcore](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore). I would suggest btcpayserver on your case, but both are "basically" bitcoind wrapper on steroids tailored for enabling applications on top of Bitcoin.

Comment: I am not new to Bitcoin. I know that I do not need Bitpay to accept them. However all tutorials I find only rely on Bitpay. I want a more technical answer which explains the steps I need to do to accept Bitcoin

Comment: Did you check btcpayserver then ? It describes exactly what you need "Start Accepting Bitcoin Payments With 0% Fees & No Third-party" and this is basically an API you will interact with in PHP. Your goal is to accept bitcoin payment, not building a wallet.